# MySQL query with LIKE returns incomplete results

Tags: mysql, sql-like

When I query my product database I get incomplete results (both in PHP and PhPMyAdmin).

The product table is large (159 columns and at the moment 8000 rows).
One column holds the product title/name (VARCHAR 255).

These are some of the products:

- Royal Club Wild Orange
- Roy­al Club Bit­ter le­mon
- Roy­al Club Gin­ger ale
- Roy­al Club To­nic

In PhPMyAdmin when I query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM `Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes`
WHERE `Product_omschrijving` LIKE '%royal%'
ORDER BY `Product_omschrijving` ASC
```

I get as result:

- Royal Club Wild Orange

but not the other products...

In PhPMyAdmin when I query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM `Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes`
WHERE `Product_omschrijving` LIKE '%club%'
ORDER BY `Product_omschrijving` ASC
```

I get as result:

- Royal Club Wild Orange
- Roy­al Club Bit­ter le­mon
- Roy­al Club Gin­ger ale
- Roy­al Club To­nic

In PhPMyAdmin when I query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM `Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes`
WHERE `Product_omschrijving` LIKE '%bitter%'
ORDER BY `Product_omschrijving` ASC
```

I get as result:
no products...

Does anyone have an idea what could be the underlying issue?

I've trying to figure out what is going on.
Maybe something with the setting on the database or the number of columns?

**addition (Jan 4th 2017)**

I also use this table in a predictive search function (with JQuery autocomplete). I have put a stripped down version here:

http://www.personalbodycenter.nl/zzz_predictive_search.php

When you view the page source you can see that the availableTags field contains all the products that are in the MySql table "Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes".

Now when you type "royal" in the field you get the same 9 (but incomplete, there should be 17) results you get when you query the table directly in PhPMyAdmin.

When you type "club" in the text field you get all the values you should from the table. And you can see there are more results with "royal" in the list. These should also come up when you type "royal"!

How can the same incomplete results come up via a mysql query as well as via a jquery function?! I could be wrong but these different ways to access the information should not be related?

I already did a lot of experimenting with the table in PhPMyAdmin by reducing the table to 2 columns, changing the collation, changing the database engine, but no luck so far...

I have placed the database on a test location, so if anyone feels they can help me by logging in to PhPMyAdminto view this table and see what is going on here, I can provide the login details...

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It may help to show us the table schema.  My guess is that this issue has to do with the charset/collation the table is stored with.

Comment: my guess is `Product_omschrijving` doesn't contain the words you are searching for, as its the "Description" and not the title of the product, maybe you need to change that to be a different column?

Comment: @cmorrissey - The examples I've placed here are eaxactly as they are in the column Product_omschrijving, so it is not that :o). Furthermore, I did a large number of tests on this table and the issue pops on an a multitiude of words tested for...

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat - what is the easiest way for me to show you the table structure. I've have a feeling that that could be the underlying problem

Comment: Run the query `DESCRIBE Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes;`, that will show you the info we should need.  You can also run `SHOW CREATE TABLE Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes;` to get the SQL used to make the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hours digging and experimenting I discovered that the underlying issue here are hidden characters in the mysql table.

Mainly a specific hidden "non breaking space" character that had creeped in the data splitting words (for example when I used utf8_encode to encode a string in php it showed: RoyÂal.

These characters were invissible in PhPMyAdmin and in the list for the predictive search function) but they were there(!), causing incomplete results (e.g. the query with LIKE '%Royal%' discarded them).

I have posted a [follow up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567514/hidden-characters-in-mysql-and-how-to-gid-rid-and-prevent-them) how to deal with these hidden characters.

Comment: The post with hidden characters is removed. Can you tell what it was about

Answer (score 1):

By default, `LIKE` performs case sensitive comparison. Maybe your column values have different case. Could you try the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Nevo_Nutrient_Gehaltes
WHERE
    lower(Product_omschrijving) LIKE '%royal%'
ORDER BY
    Product_omschrijving ASC
```

Comment: It's only case sensitive if the string is stored in the database in a case sensitive charset.  From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html): "string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a case sensitive (uses a case-sensitive collation or is a binary string)"

Comment: Agreed. But we don't know the table structure yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but case sensitivity is not the issues I've tried that already